# For an open subset $D$ of a normed space, its multiple $\alpha D$ is also open

Tags: normed-spaces

> $D$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$ and $E=\{\alpha x : x\in D, \alpha>0\}$
>
> Prove that $E$ is open iff $D$ is open

For each $\alpha x \in E \exists$ a ball $B_\epsilon (\alpha x)\subset E$. Can we conclude that there is a ball of radius $1/ \alpha$ at the corresponding $x\in D$?

Similarly for each $B_\epsilon(x)\subset D$, can we say $B_{\alpha \epsilon} (\alpha x) \subset E$?

Does this proof work?

Comment: Yes, because for every $x,y\in D$ we have $|y-x|<\varepsilon \iff |\alpha y - \alpha x|=\alpha |y-x|<\alpha \varepsilon$.

Comment: @Trouble thank you, thats what I was looking for